# Sharepoint 2010. Search

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

I am not very familiar with sharepoint so probably this can be builtin function or something....

I have 200 sites and i need really fast search inside documents and pages.

What is the best way to perform search and cache some items?

- I need also to show search items while customer types text inside text box. How can i perform search for that purpose(Ajax+WCF. question about sharepoint API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:
[Getting started with enterprise search in SharePoint 2010 Products (white paper)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631149.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This is no simple task with pitfalls you should be aware of:

- Find-on-type against the search index could lead to a overload of the system with a bottle neck to the SQL server (High traffic between front end and back end).
- Caching is difficult since for a search you probably want to cache per user to avoid security issues.

Use paging to avoid returning the whole set:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query;
// ...
Query query = new FullTextSqlQuery(site);
query.StartRow = x;
query.RowLmit = 10;
```

Check out our product [MatchPoint](http://www.colygon.com). MatchPoint is a application framework for SharePoint that includes a set of web parts providing the functionality you require for this task.